# How to prevent CiviCRM contact from receiving emails for Scheduled Reminders

Tags: email, scheduled-reminders, opt-out

[image: E]
When a contact (dashboard) is edited, I see Communication Preferences as 
the option where I can tick NO BULK EMAILS or under Privacy "Do not mail" 
Will that stop the emails from being sent during scheduled reminders(ran
 through CRON)
Where is the code for the same located in the CiviCRM core? Can I add
 event subscriber to it ?
I am using sendgrid as Mailer

Comment: There's a related discussion here: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1378. According to that, currently they WILL receive cron scheduled reminders for "Do Not Mail".

Answer (score 2):

From UI you can set the contact email to 'On-hold' this will prevent contact from getting any automated email from CiviCRM. The other option is use to [mailing hooks](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks) to abort emails being sent based on some flag set for the client.

HTH

Pradeep